# Set Background image in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code in my JavaScript&CSS to create a div & set a bg image :

```
var incrementEnabled = document.createElement('div');
incrementEnabled.className = "SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En"; 
this.divElt.appendChild(incrementEnabled);

.SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En {
background-color: white;
float:left;
position: fixed;
width:230px;
height:65px;
top:125px;
left:360px;
background:url("../images/icons/IcnListAddRecipient_En.png") no-repeat center;
```

path of url is also proper but image is not getting set.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHk68/) works fine (even with quotes). Check that `this.divElt` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check with firebug (or any other developer tools in your favorite browser) what happens?

- does your div show up at all?
- is the class correctly set?
- what happens to the background attribute?

And why are you using float AND position:fixed? The float:left doesn't do anything.

And btw, I always use single quotes, it's just fine using them :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `url("../images/icons/IcnListAddRecipient_En.png")` but `url(../images/icons/IcnListAddRecipient_En.png)`

Replace css with this and I hope the problem will be solved

```
.SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En {
background-color: white;
float:left;
position: fixed;
width:230px;
height:65px;
top:125px;
left:360px;
background:url(../images/icons/IcnListAddRecipient_En.png) no-repeat center;
```

Comment: Why without quotes? Does it matter?

Comment: I might not but I think is safer to use without, I always use without, google too,

Comment: According to [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-image) and [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri) single and double quotes are optional, so it doesn't matter.